# Change Owner of Database Diagram in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to change the owner of a database diagram in SQL Server 2005. Currently it is owned by me (domain\username.diagramName) and I would like to change it to be owned by dbo (dbo.diagramName). I thought I could use sp_changeobjectowner, but I believe that is only for tables, stored procedures, etc... I think this is pretty easy, I just haven't been able to find anything through a google search.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the end, I had to remove that users schema then run the following update...

```
-- to identify the diagram id, name, & owner

select *
from dbo.sysdiagrams


-- to manually change the owner of a diagram
-- note: i derived that the principal_id =1 for dbo from above query

update 
dbo.sysdiagrams set principal_id =1 where diagram_id = 1
```

I ended up getting the help I needed from a DBA here on campus.

Comment: As can be seen in by running `SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals`, `principal_id` number 1 is the `dbo` principal. I imagine one might also consider `principal_id` 0, which is public.

Answer (score 14):

```
UPDATE dbo.sysdiagrams 
SET principal_id = 1
```

Set a WHERE clause if needs be. The text above suggests you need to remove the user from the database, but I didn't have to do that. I'm using SQL2008 R2.

Answer (score 5):

```
USE [db_name]
UPDATE dbo.sysdiagrams 
SET principal_id = 1
```

if above statement not work, you can take an edit on this table with right click on the dbo.sysdiagrams and select Edit top 200 rows, then you can set principal_id column for all records manually set to 1

Comment: The no sql method worked for me. I didn't fully understand at first what you meant @hamed aj but yes, to be more explicit, under System Tables, rt click on dbo.sysdiagrams and choose to edit top 200 rows. In table that is then displayed you simply find the row defining your diagram of interest, and change the value in the principal_id to 1. Go refresh the diagrams listing and you will see it update to dbo as the owner.

Answer (score 2):

This article states you will have to remove yourself as a user of the db. The open it up with the user of your choice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171972(VS.80).aspx

Comment: When I attempt to delete the user I get... 

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Drop failed for User 'domain\username'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://bit.ly/gHA9

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15138)

For help, click: http://bit.ly/2lzKpz

Comment: I imagine there is a schema called 'jason' you'll need to change object from that schema to it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx

Comment: I removed the schema and was able to remove the user. When I went back to the diagram, the owner then got changed to public. Still not what I want. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Although it wouldn't have helped in this case (because it just re-creates the entire `sysdiagrams` row), these scripts

[ScriptDiagram2005](http://conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2005/) or [ScriptDiagram2008](http://conceptdevelopment.net/Database/ScriptDiagram2008/)

allow you to create an *INSERT script* of the diagrams 'content', to be re-run against the source database (or a backup, or scripted copy, or whatever). You could easily (knowing what you now know about `principal_id`) re-create the diagram with a new owner as well.

Just find and edit the rest of this statement in the script

```
INSERT INTO sysdiagrams ([name], [principal_id], [version], [definition])
```

the real benefit is being able to source-control/backup the text file...