# How to change the schema for a diagram?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, schema, database-schema

Diagrams created with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio have their default schema set to *dbo*. It seems that there is no way to set another schema when creating a diagram.

For tables,

```
alter schema NewSchemaName transfer dbo.TableName
```

moves a specified table to the new schema. But the same command does not work for diagrams.

Is it possible to change the schema once the diagram created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Diagrams do not have schemas because they aren't rows/objects in sys.objects.

They [have owners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186345.aspx) but not in the schema/user separation sense.

Answer (score 5):

Though diagrams are not attached to schemas, changing the owner will change the "schema" displayed in SSMS.

[Change Owner of Database Diagram in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865162/change-owner-of-database-diagram-in-sql-server-2005)

As you want to change from "dbo" to another schema, just make sure your destination schema equates to a valid user or role in the database and change the diagram's Principal_ID to match that user's or role's Principal_ID.